# FELM weights argument broken in R?

Tags: r, regression

In R, the weights parameter in FELM says the weight variable is not found even though it is in the data set.

```
# Reproducible example for felm weights problem
df <- NULL
df$y <- rnorm(1000)
df$x0 <- rnorm(1000)
df$x1 <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)
df$weightvar <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T)

df1 <- data.frame(df)
reg <- felm(y ~ x0 | factor(x1) | 0 | 0
           , data = df1, weights = weightvar)
```

> Error in eval(mf[[wpos]], pf): object 'weightvar' not found Traceback:
>
> 1. felm(y ~ x0 | factor(x1) | 0 | 0, data = df1, weights = weightvar)
> 2. makematrix(mf, contrasts, pf = parent.frame(), clustervar, wildcard = wildcard)
> 3. eval(mf[[wpos]], pf)
> 4. eval(mf[[wpos]], pf)

Comment: Does `weights = df1$weightvar` work? I think R knows how to look up the variables in the formula from the `data` argument but for other arguments you might have to manually specify.

Comment: You are correct, that solves it!